# Filter by length of array in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have data stored in [avro](https://avro.apache.org/) format.  One of the fields of each record (`array_field`, say) is an array.  Using Pig how do I obtain only the records that have arrays with, for example, `length(array_field) >= 2` and then store the results in avro files using the same schema as the original input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable with something like code below:

```
A = LOAD '$INPUT' USING AvroStorage();
B = FILTER A BY SIZE(array_field) >= 2;
STORE B INTO '$OUTPUT' USING AvroStorage('schema', '<schema_here>');
```